# check if exist on postgres array django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

i have this zone like east west north south and i have added states in all 4 zone.every states stored in array type like this ids:
{cd26ddeb-04cb-4d9a-8c7f-51d5d389f475,bc44618d-3a21-475b-8d74-c0542abb173b,18695611-256e-4506-a087-596f8914551d}
what i'm trying to do is whenever i have any new state it should check on all zone if it exist then do nothing otherwise add this.
Issue is i'm passing new states that need to add with previous added states. then i'm checking with all zone states if not exist then add this to new_state list and pass to data but this part not working:

```
if state not in all_state:
   #its not filtering states returning all
    new_state.append(state)


@api_view(['POST'])
@login_required_message
def zoneEdit(request):
    data = decode_data(request.data.copy())
    new_state = []
    try:
        try:
            zone_queryset = Zone.objects.get(uid=data['uid'])

            all_state = Zone.objects.values_list('state',flat=True)
            print(all_state, "all_state")
            data["created_by"] = request.user.uid
            for state in data['state']:  
                if state not in all_state:
       #its not filtering states returning all
                    new_state.append(state)
            print(new_state, "to be added")                
            zone_serializer_obj = ZoneSerializer(zone_queryset, data=new_state)
            if zone_serializer_obj.is_valid():
                try:
                    city_save = zone_serializer_obj.save()
                    return CustomeResponse(request=request, comment=ZONE_NAME_UPDATE, data=json.dumps(zone_serializer_obj.data, cls=UUIDEncoder), status=status.HTTP_200_OK, message=ZONE_NAME_UPDATE)
                except Exception as e:
                    return CustomeResponse(request=request, log_data=json.dumps(str(e), cls=UUIDEncoder), message=SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG+" mv54 "+str(e), data=json.dumps({}, cls=UUIDEncoder), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, validate_errors=1)
            else:
                return CustomeResponse(request=request, comment=FIELDS_NOT_VALID, data=json.dumps(zone_serializer_obj.errors, cls=UUIDEncoder), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, validate_errors=1)
        else:
            return CustomeResponse(request=request, comment=FIELDS_NOT_VALID, data=json.dumps({}, cls=UUIDEncoder), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, validate_errors=1)
    except City.DoesNotExist:
        return CustomeResponse(request=request, comment=ZONE_NAME_NOT_FOUND, message=ZONE_NAME_NOT_FOUND, data=json.dumps({}, cls=UUIDEncoder), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, validate_errors=1)
except Exception as e:
    error_str = KEY_MISSING if type(e) is KeyError else UID_IS_NOT_VALID
    return CustomeResponse(request=request, log_data=json.dumps(str(e), cla=UUIDEncoder), comment=error_str,  message=error_str, data=json.dumps({}, cls=UUIDEncoder),  status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, validate_errors=1)
```

i can pass multiple state to added in array at once with previous existing state on same zone.if any bettery way to check if which state exist or not with all zone state please suggest

Comment: Can you include your models? I'm not exactly sure what the problem here is, Can you re-phrase the desired Zone-State logic?

Comment: solved it......